# How do you change the text "Update failed. You are probably offline." <- can't seem to change this default text in my wordpress

Tags: javascript

How do you change the text "Update failed. You are probably offline." <- can't seem to change this default text in my wordpress.

Doing

```
    grep -rnH 'You are probably offline' .
```

gets

```
     ./wp-includes/js/dist/api-fetch.js:856:      message: Object(external_this_wp_i18n_["__"])('You are probably offline.')
```

and

```
     ./wp-includes/js/dist/api-fetch.min.js:2:
```

i edited both text by replacing . with ... BUT it doesnt change at all. can someone try and answer how to get this done? I would like to replace the text with "Please reload." because the firewall is blocking the access after too frequent updates of the wordpress so i would like my user to reload the page instead of this default msg.

```
     ./wp-includes/js/dist/api-fetch.js:856:      message: Object(external_this_wp_i18n_["__"])('You are probably offline....')
```

can someone help? thx

Comment: Make sure your caching is turning off - your browser may be saving old files from your server (non-edited). I was going to mention the same thing - just edit the core files. The problem with editing the core files is as soon as WordPress has an update - your edits go away. (not good for a client). You would have to build that in a WordPress plugin - you will most likely use something like `str_replace`. Here is the documentation page for that: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: i suspect caching also but how do i turn it off? why is caching affecting this since it's ,js files?

Comment: Depending on the setting on your browser - all files (including Javascript) are saved on your browser when you load a page. If you are doing a lot of WordPress sites or development - I would start using Gulp - to handing reloading of the page (and caching issues). The way to handle it is a few ways. 1. Hard-refresh your browser (this can get old) 2. Edit the wp_config file in your WordPress and edit `'WP_CACHE',true` and change it to `'WP_CACHE',false`.